# Validate Locale string in Golang

Tags: go, locale

I am trying to write Go code that will check whether or not a string represents a valid locale. From the documentation, I've gotten to here:

```
import "golang.org/x/text/language"

locale := "en"
tag, err := language.Parse(locale)
if err != nil {
    return errors.New("Invalid locale: " + locale)
}
```

I think that this should work, and it seems to work most of the time, but it doesn't always give me an error when I expect it to. For example, if I say `locale := "bcd"` I don't get an error.

What am I missing here?

Comment: May it be that you're confusing *valid* locale strings with strings identifying locales *known to the package?* I mean, "bcd" looks like a perfectly legal locale name to me.  The rules of locale naming defined in the corresponding RFC are complicated but they put no restriction on the locale names being predefined (and that would be a dumb thing to do).

Comment: So if you indeed do confuse these things I'd recommend diving into the package's source code to see how you could compare a locale name supplied by the user with the list of locales known to the package.

Comment: you could copy and paste this file into your package and edit to taste https://github.com/golang/text/blob/master/language/tables.go

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`bcd` is a valid ISO 639-3 language code for the North Babar language, and by extension it's a valid locale name.